# Why the "focusin" event handler isn't called?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, focusin

Why in the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/a5puC/1/) the `focusin` event handler isn't called ?

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'></div>
<div id='button'>Click Here</div>
<div id='output'></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').live('focusin', function() {
        $('#output').html('focusin'); // Why this not happens ?
    });
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $('#button').hide();
        build_inputs();
    });    
});
function build_inputs() {
    var html = "<input type='text' /> \
                <br /> \
                <input type='text' />";
    $('#wrapper').append(html);
    $('#wrapper').fadeIn(500, function() {
        $('input:first').focus();
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    display: none;
    background: #aaa;
    width: 170px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I am confused at what you are trying to do? It works for me after the inputs have been appended.

Comment: Unless you are talking about it not focusing after the `fadeIn` try `$("input:first").focus().focusin();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, I'm not positive why, `.focus()` doesn't trigger the `focusin` event.

You can replicate this behaviour by changing the focus line to add `.trigger('focusin')`.

so your fadeIn code becomes:

```
$('#wrapper').fadeIn(500, function() {
    $('input:first').focus().trigger('focusin');
});
```

You can test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/yt7Jd/

EDIT: As Jason mentioned, you can also call the `.focusin()` method instead of the `.trigger('focusin')`.

EDIT 2: It appears to be a bug in 1.4.3. It has been logged with the jQuery team for fixing: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7340

Comment: he can call `.focusin()` also as I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: @Jason: Indeed he can. Interestingly the documentation for `.focusin()` doesn't say this.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm still wondering why `focus()` doesn't trigger the `focusin` event. Is this a known behavior ?

Comment: @Misha: It appears to be a bug in jQuery 1.4.3. If you go to the jsfiddle I made, remove the `.trigger()`, change the jquery version to 1.4.2 then your code works as expected.

Comment: Wow, Unbelievable! I just moved from 1.4.2 to 1.4.3 :) Thanks a lot!