# Focusin using live not working -jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach a `focusin event` on a future element using jquery 1.5.2. Just to clarify,[this has also been attempted using jQuery 1.7.2 with the same issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/5T3SG/4/)

The event is not firing as i expected it to. Yet a similar click event works correctly using `.live`

I've put together an example here for you to take a look at my code. Hopefully this will not been a simple issue (although it always seems to be!).

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5T3SG/2/)

This is my focusin event i am trying to attach

```
$(".active").live("focusin", function() {
    $(this).text("focusin using live");
});
```

I believe i have found some related questions, but im unable to fix my code using them. I would prefer an explanation over a "here is your code corrected answer".

If you think i need to add more information to my question please leave a comment.

**Related**

[jQuery focusin and focusout live events are not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524454/jquery-focusin-and-focusout-live-events-are-not-firing)

[Why the "focusin" event handler isn't called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039952/why-the-focusin-event-handler-isnt-called)

Comment: Why are you using such an old jQuery version?

Comment: Is an aging website that i am working on. This also doesn't work on jQuery 1.7.2. See here (http://jsfiddle.net/5T3SG/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to focus the element if you expect the `focusin` event to trigger. The fact that you are applying a DOM element the `.active` class doesn't mean that you are focusing it.

```
$('.active').live('focusin', function() {
    $(this).text('focusin using live');
});

$('.active').focus();
​
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5T3SG/6/).

Another thing you will notice is that `.live()` supports the `focusin` event starting from jQuery 1.7.1. Obviously in this version of jQuery, `.live()` is deprecated and you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('focusin', '.active', function() {
    $(this).text('focusin using on');
});

$('.active').focus();
```

​